# PGF-Plot not at centre

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles

I would like to plot some circles with `pgfplots` inside a diagram, however, they are always off-centered.

```
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm, compat=1.12}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-2.5, xmax=2.5,
ymin=-2.5, ymax=2.5,
xtick={-2,-1,0,1,2},
ytick={-2,-1,0,1,2},
grid=major,
]
% standard tikz syntax:
\draw[black] (0,0)
ellipse [
x radius=1, y radius=2];
\draw[red] (0,0)
ellipse [rotate=90,
x radius=1, y radius=2];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

According to the pgf-plot documentation, this should give me (http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf, page 298)

[image: PGF Documentaion]

But instead, I get something like this:

[image: My diagram]

Could you please show me my mistake?

Comment: Why do you have two different `compat`?

Comment: This is your first question, so Welcome to the site. You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have used `compat` two times with `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}` at the last. So this prevails over `compat=1.12`. In older versions of `pgfplots` the coordinates for drawing should be mentioned as

```
\draw[black] (axis cs: 0,0) ellipse [...
```

Note the `axis cs:`. If you don't use `axis cs:`, the `tikz` coordinates are used for which the origin `(0,0)` lies at the lower left corner and since `pgfplots` clips the area you get only the first quadrant. Only from version `1.12` onwards one can use `(0,0)`.

Hence, if you have an older version, use `axis cs:`. On version 1.12, we get this:

```
\documentclass[border=2]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm, compat=1.12}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}   %% why 2 times?
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-2.5, xmax=2.5,
ymin=-2.5, ymax=2.5,
xtick={-2,-1,0,1,2},
ytick={-2,-1,0,1,2},
grid=major,
]
% standard tikz syntax:
\draw[black] (0,0)
ellipse [
x radius=1, y radius=2];
\draw[red] (0,0)
ellipse [rotate=90,
x radius=1, y radius=2];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the older version `1.5.1`, you are loading, this would be

```
\documentclass[border=2]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm, compat=1.12}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}   %% why 2 times?
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-2.5, xmax=2.5,
ymin=-2.5, ymax=2.5,
xtick={-2,-1,0,1,2},
ytick={-2,-1,0,1,2},
grid=major,
]
% standard tikz syntax:
\draw[black] (axis cs: 0,0)
ellipse [
x radius=1, y radius=2];
\draw[red] (axis cs: 0,0)
ellipse [rotate=90,
x radius=1, y radius=2];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

BTW, you don't need to rotate the ellipse but just interchange the `x` and `y` radii like

```
\draw[red] (axis cs: 0,0)
ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You specify `compat` twice. If you use just

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
```

it works fine. At some point in its development, PGFPLOTS made draw commands in an axis environment default to the `axis cs` coordinate system. Using the earlier `compat=1.5`, `\draw` uses the generic PGF coordinates, and it looks like PGF axes are drawn at PGF (0,0).